# Retrieving page weight programmatically in Selenium Framework

Tags: performance, selenium, automation, html

I am trying to build page performance related utilities in selenium framework on .NET. For page performance I am considering **page load time** and **page weight** as the outputs. I am planning to calculate page timing metrics using WebTimings API of the browser. But I am not able to find out any way I'll be able to get the size of the page that gets loaded, **programmatically**

- Are there any libraries that will help me achieve it? Or can Selenium be used for this use case?
- Does page weight mean the sum size of all the resources that get downloaded, or just a .html file? What should I consider when I want to calculate page weight?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you want to do something using [Browsermob Proxy](http://bmp.lightbody.net/) , which will give you all those stats via a [.har file](http://www.neustar.biz/blog/what-is-a-har-file) .